# R data.table/regex - tstrsplit on first and last occurrence of character

Tags: r, regex, split

I'm using data.table's `tstrsplit` to create three columns from a single column for multiple tables. The source column is a character vector with 2 to 4 spaces. I need to split on the first and last space.

In the case of the table with a source column with two spaces the solution doesn't require regex:

tbl = data.table('source.col'=c('enable synergistic vortals', 'architect compelling niches', 'mesh global deliverables'))

```
> tbl
                    source.col
1:  enable synergistic vortals
2: architect compelling niches
3:    mesh global deliverables

> tbl[, c('before', 'base', 'after') := tstrsplit(source.col, ' ', fixed=T)]
> tbl
                    source.col    before        base        after
1:  enable synergistic vortals    enable synergistic      vortals
2: architect compelling niches architect  compelling       niches
3:    mesh global deliverables      mesh      global deliverables
```

I haven't figured out a regex for working with tables with `source.col` having n spaces greater than 2.

```
> tbl = data.table('source.col'=c('enable synergistic vortals implement', 'architect compelling niches systems', 'mesh global deliverables enable'))
> tbl
                             source.col
1: enable synergistic vortals implement
2:  architect compelling niches systems
3:      mesh global deliverables enable
```

I have a reliable regex for splitting on the [last space](https://frightanic.com/software-development/regex-match-last-occurrence/), `' (?!.* )'`, but the options I've found for splitting on first space, `^[^ ]+`, return empty strings for all but the last new column.

My question is two-fold, 1) how to split on the first space and 2) how to combine the regex for splitting on the first and the regex for splitting on the last (with | perhaps) to get results like this:

```
> tbl
                             source.col    before                base     after
1: enable synergistic vortals implement    enable synergistic vortals implement
2:  architect compelling niches systems architect   compelling niches   systems
3:      mesh global deliverables enable      mesh global deliverables    enable
```

Comment: `stringr::str_match(x, "^(\\S+)\\s+(.*?)\\s+(\\S+)$")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fread` after creating a delimiter with `sub` (from `base R`)

```
library(data.table)
tbl[,c('before', 'base', 'after') := fread(text =
      sub("^(\\w+) (.*) (\\w+)$", "\\1,\\2,\\3", 
        source.col), header = FALSE)]
tbl
#                             source.col    before                base     after
#1: enable synergistic vortals implement    enable synergistic vortals implement
#2:  architect compelling niches systems architect   compelling niches   systems
#3:      mesh global deliverables enable      mesh global deliverables    enable
```

Comment: interesting...any particular reason for this approach? fast?

Comment: @ConnerM. `fread` is fast.  Can you please check the timings on your data if it is slow wrt to tstrsplit

Comment: @ConnerM. i am not getting your point, can you update with a different data showing the issue

Comment: @ConnerM. if the number of spacess is variable, use `\\s+` i.e one or more spaces `tbl[,c('before', 'base', 'after') := fread(text =
      sub("^(\\w+)\\s+(.*)\\s+(\\w+)$", "\\1,\\2,\\3", 
        source.col), header = FALSE)]`

Comment: @ConnerM thanks, can you update with a new example so that it is more clear